# Insert string at particular location on a loop

Tags: python, sql, string

I have a csv file containing product numbers and I need to insert these into a string which will be later used as a SQL query. I can read and append the values fine but I cant format it correctly.

```
import csv

query = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE prodNum ='

with open('numbers.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        num = "prodNum = "+(row[0] )
        query += num

print(query)
```

The problem is I need to insert the read value into () , if the file had 3 values, I need the output to be like the below for example

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (prodNum = 111) OR (prodNum = 222) OR (prodNum = 333)
```

Comment: Can you share few rows of csv file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you are trying to do, but maybe this does the trick?

```py
query = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE '

with open('numbers.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        num = "(prodNum = "+row[0]+") OR "
        query += num
query = query[:-4]
print(query)
```

Comment: We are not sure of contents inside csv file. User should mention that

Comment: Well I would think that each row has just the number.. I guessed that the issue was just on how to change the string accordingly, but we will see

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks

Comment: @Gary What if the column being considered contains the same value multiple times? The query would contain unnecessary WHERE clauses

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a different approach here, which, however, should ultimately outperform what you are trying to do.  Instead of building your SQL query this way, I recommend instead reading the product numbers into a separate table in your SQL database.  Most SQL databases support very fast bulk CSV loading features, so this should be easy (and safe to do).  Once you have this table in place, you may issue just a single query:

```
query = """SELECT *
FROM Products p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM nums n WHERE n.prodNum = p.prodNum)"""
```

Note this approach leaves open the possibility of using an index on the new table of product numbers, and should be faster than what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution does not always provide the correct result. For example, if the file `numbers.csv` contains

```
1,2,3
2,1,2
2,3,1
4,3,2
```

then the accepted solution returns

`"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE(prodNum = 1) OR (prodNum = 2) OR (prodNum = 2) OR (prodNum = 4)"`

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('numbers.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    values = set(row[0] for row in readCSV)
    where = " OR ".join(f"(prodNum={v})" for v in values)
    query = f"SELECT * from Products WHERE {where}"
```

which returns

`SELECT * from Products WHERE (prodNum=4) OR (prodNum=2) OR (prodNum=1)`